# Posting an Image on top of Background Using SASS

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, sass

I'm trying to place a small image on top of another image using SASS and HTML. I'm a beginner to coding so I'm not sure what it I'm doing wrong but it may be obvious to someone else.

I'm trying to place the small image labelled "mklogo" overtop the "maze" image, however the only image I see is the "maze" image.

Could somebody give me a hand?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Maze Assignment</title>
        <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
    <div id="mklogo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the SASS under the .scss file.

```
html, body{
    background: url("../images/maze.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    image-rendering:-moz-crisp-edges;

}

#mklogo{
    background: url("../images/mkLogo.png");
    width:5vw;
    height:5vw;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You've positioned the `#mklogo` absolutely, which removes it from the document flow. Unless you set a height and width on the `body` the `body` will not expand to fit `#mklogo`. Try setting an explicit size on the `body` (like `100vw` and `100vh`) and this should work.

Also, only set the background image on the `body`, not `html`.